# Best Location to store oAuth tokens

Tags: r, oauth

I am writing an R package called rCharts, which allows users to create, customize and publish JS charts from R. One of the options for publishing is to gist.github.com.

I have implemented basic authentication using Github's v3 API, which uses username and password to fetch a token, and then use the token to create a gist.

Now, I want to store the token, the first time it is generated, so that (a) users are not prompted for username and pwd every time, and (b) prevent token proliferation by generating a fresh token every time.

I thought of a couple of locations I could store the token.

1. rCharts package directory.
2. `~/.rCharts`
3. `.rProfile`

I am trying to think through the pros and cons of each of these approaches. I like using `.rProfile`, but what if the user opens R from a different directory.

I would appreciate if someone can help me understand what would be the best solution.

UPDATE. Thanks to @hadley I figured out that I was actually using OAuth and NOT basic authorization. Using basic authorization, it is really easy to post gists. Here is my code. I believe, the safest way to retrieve username and password is using `options`. The user-agent string is required due to some recent changes in Github's API.

```
require(httr)
POST(
  url = 'https://api.github.com/gists',
  config = c(
    authenticate('username', 'password', type = 'basic'),
    add_headers("User-Agent" = "Dummy")
  ),
  body = body
)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use github's basic auth? Then you don't need to worry about storing tokens.

Comment: I am using the basic auth mentioned [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-use). I used httr to do oauth, but it requires creating an app on github first, and then browser based verification. My current approach bypasses all of that. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/R/gist.R)

Comment: (1) You don't need to generate the token, just use basic auth with every request. (2) You can use either httr or RCurl for this. (3) Asking for a password with readline is a bad idea

Comment: I don't understand. The basic auth does ask for a password and generates a token which is required for subsequent requests. I can bypass readline by using `options`, so not a major issue.

Comment: I think I get it. I am confusing basic auth with oauth. Let me get my head around this.